# How to highlight several dates in bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code snippets:
    
     Start Date

```
$('#date_checkin').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

Let me know how to highlight several dates in datetimepicker?

Comment: I have several date range pair values, so would like to highlight all those date ranges. Couldn't find out any options in datetimepicker.

Comment: What do you mean by highlight? I have no idea what that implies in this context.

Comment: Let's say I have two date values: Check-In & Check-Out. I'd like to make all the dates as selected status between these two date values.

Comment: @YenneInfo not same plugin so don't see how it could be a duplicate

Comment: Provide link to docs for plugin being used. Does API even support multiple dates?

Comment: It is bootstrap datetimepicker used by many apps.